# The result strange in strings

Tags: php

I've got a problem, I make some procedure and produces these two strings in output

```
string(46) "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70"
string(32) "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70"
```

As you see the string length is `32` and the `var_dump` function supposed to give string length of both equal, but it doesn't as above.

This is the result after dumping to hex

```
string(92) "32303263623936326163353930373562393634623037313532643233346237300000000000000000000000000000"
string(64) "3230326362393632616335393037356239363462303731353264323334623730"
```

Do you have any idea how the two string can be differed like above?
And how can I make the above one to be normalize as the other?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code that produces this output?

Comment: try trimming it, could be white space?

Comment: So you have NULL characters, which are not printable but are still bytes. If you don't need them, you should fix your code so it doesn't produce them in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same character encoding scheme for both strings? @ÁlvaroG.Vicario 's point is more probable though...

Comment: Thanks to Alvaro G. Vicario. It's NULL byte! Please make as a post, I will mark your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $myString = rtrim($myString);
```

It kills space null tab etc...